# how to add data to existing json object by post method?

Tags: angularjs, json, ionic-framework

i have a json object user.js

```
[{
    "id": 1,
    "username": "vishnu",
    "password": "password"
},{
    "id": 2,
    "username": "vishnu2",
    "password": "password"
},{
    "id": 2,
    "username": "vishnu@gmail.com",
    "password": "password"
}]
```

and i have created a service to access data from it, now i want to add data to it by using the same service with post method.help me.

```
angular.module('starter.service')
.factory('authService', function($http) {
  var service = {};

  service.GetByUsername = function() {
    return $http.get('/js/user.json');
  }

  return service;
})
```

service is given above.edit in the same code if u can.

add

```
    "id": 3,

    "username": "yourself@gmail.com",

    "password": "password"
```

Answer (score 0):

Default POST http call:

```
  $http({
       method: 'POST',
       url: 'URL',
      data: yourJsonObject
    }).success(function (data, status) {
    }).error(function (data, status) {
    });
```

Comment: y success functin has 2 parametrs?

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http . data,
status ,headers,config,statusText. If it helped, upvote and mark as solution cheers